# Why when I try to render a page with an error when loading a site using the module vue-template-compiler?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I try to start the web server, the web server starts. But when you load the main page of the site (with the rendered idea using the module "view-template-compiler"), the site does not load. The console does not write anything. Tried "npm run dev" and errors can be found below.

```
const express = require('express'),
          app = express()

const serverPort = process.env.PORT || 3000
const compiler = require('vue-template-compiler')


app.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
  compiler.compile('src/views/index.vue')
})

app.listen(serverPort, () => {
  console.log("Веб сервер запустился успешно")
})
```

And get errors when npm run dev:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'F:\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'F:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.14.1
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: dev
4 verbose stack     at run (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:418:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:373:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:416:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:280:12
4 verbose stack     at F:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
5 verbose cwd F:\sunrise\sunrise-web
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
7 verbose argv "F:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "F:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
8 verbose node v10.14.1
9 verbose npm  v6.4.1
10 error missing script: dev
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-sunrise",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "element-ui": "^2.10.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "simplebar-vue": "^1.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-clipboard2": "^0.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-scroll-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuebar": "0.0.20",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-component": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass": "^1.18.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This looks like a package.json issue. If you look down the error stack, you will see `Error: missing script: dev`. You probably still need to associate keyword `dev` with your server startup command.

Comment: @LenJoseph can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Please add the `script` section of your `package.json` file.

Comment: @LenJoseph i added package.json`s code in post, can you check it?

Comment: `npm run serve`should do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to resolve the issue.

1) Just use `npm run serve`: your development server is configured to run on the `serve` keyword by default.

2) Add a script to your script section for `dev` like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run serve",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

Then `npm dev` would run your server by proxy. I don't know why you'd want to do this, but if you really prefer to use `dev` as your start command, that's how you'd do it.

Comment: or you rename the key `serve` to `dev`